How to pass the output of a command to a warp prompt?
In Warp, I want to pass the output of a command directly into the Warp AI prompt in a single step. For example, I want to generate a commit message based on the output of git diff.
My goal is to streamline this into a single AI call, where the output of git diff is automatically passed into the initial prompt.
I tried the following approaches, but neither worked:
command | do something with the output of the command
command | tee do something with the output of the command

But they didn’t work.
Is there a way to pass the output of a command directly to Warp’s AI prompt in a single step?
